# Objective-C & Interacting with Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm looking to interact with my Microsoft Dynamics CRM system from my iPhone, performing tasks such as pulling down, updating, creating and deleting records.

Is this possible?  If so, can anyone link me to any good resources on the matter or provide me with any information you feel would be relevant?

Many thanks,

Jack

Comment: Are you looking for an existing tool/product to interact with CRM 2011 from your iOS device or are you looking for guidance on coding such a tool/product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this will be possible and there are at least some relevant pointers in the [CRM SDK (Development from Non-.NET Clients in Microsoft Dynamics CRM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327838.aspx) however general support and anecdotal information is sparse (in fact the referenced topic and it's links are all that exist in an official sense).

You will be accessing via the SOAP endpoint and the link to the WSDL for that is exposed [via the CRM UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309401.aspx) (Settings > Customizations > Developer Resources).

I'd start with downloading the [CRM SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004) and reading the topics I linked to.

***Caveat** - I know nothing of Objective-C or IOS*

Comment: Thanks for the tips, need to wait to award to bounty though, don't think I've forgotten.

Comment: Kudos is enough - the bounty is just a bonus ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know anything about this, but maybe that'll help: http://www.cwrmobility.com/

If your looking to develop something yourlself, this might help: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13621

Comment: -1 OPs tags strongly imply this is a dev task so only your 2nd link is relevant. The second link however refers to CRM 4.0 and the OP is interested in CRM 2011.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, you'll need to use the web services API.

[MSDN web services API docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150838.aspx)

It uses JScript, so on the iPhone, you should use NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection to retrieve the data coming back.

Here is another link for using JSON, as iOS has a JSON parser built in now

[MS CRM using JSON](http://inogic.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/read-records-synchronously-using-json_13.html)

Comment: -1 First link is for CRM 4.0 but OP is seeking info on CRM 2011 as per tags