# What are the ways available to connect iOS app to fetch data from or via microsoft dynamics crm 2011?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to develop an iOS application which will fetch the data from or through Microsoft dynamics CRM 2011. But don't know where to start with. Any links/help/startingPoint is highly appreciated? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581397/objective-c-interacting-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm

Comment: Thanks Rushabh :) Atleast I got start